# Create 2 column PowerPoint slides with RMarkdown in a Loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

I am looking to create multiple 2 column PowerPoint slides using RMarkdown from a loop.  This will allow the number of slides to be dynamic based on the input data.  The normal syntax to do this is:

```
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

:::
::: {.column}

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

:::
::::::::::::::
```

However, when putting this into a loop, the column syntax is evaluated as text, not as markdown code.  This results in the column code simply printing out on the slide instead of creating 2 columns.

The below code wont execute properly, but it demonstrates what I am hoping to accomplish.

```
list <- c("Slide 1", "Slide 2", "Slide 3")

for (slide in list) {

 cat(paste0("\n\n## Summary of ", slide, " \n\n"))

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

:::
::: {.column}

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

:::
:::::::::::::: 


}
```